# How to set money manually in payu money

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payumoney

I want to set money in amount field a fixed amount. I tried this one but getting an error after going to payumoney payment page. the error is amount invalid and checksum error

Page 1

```
   <?php $myVariable1 = "2";?>

  <form action="http://nailspaexperience.com/old-manish/App_Data/" method="post">
                    <p>£42.00</p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="textarea1" value="<?php echo $myVariable1; ?>">
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>



  Page 2 

 session_start(); // needs to be before anything else on page to use 
$_SESSION
  // this page outputs the textarea1 from the session IF it exists
  $textarea1 = "2"; // set var to avoid errors
  if(isset($_SESSION['textarea1'])){
    $textarea1 = $_SESSION['textarea1'];
  }



  <div  class="form-input">
  <label>Amount: </label>
   <input name="textarea1" placeholder="Enter amount" value="<?php echo $textarea1; ?>" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    For payu money, they have defined parameters with defined input names.
    Replace your name="textarea" to name="amount" and try.

    Let me know still your facing the issue.

    Updated Answer

     $posted['key'] = $MERCHANT_KEY;
        $posted['txnid'] = $txnid;
        $posted['amount'] = 100;
        $posted['firstname'] = 'Bhushan';
        $posted['lastname'] = Lunkad;
        $posted['email'] = 'Your email';
        $posted['phone'] = 'mobile';
        $posted['productinfo'] = 'Product info";
``      $posted['surl'] = 'success url';
        $posted['furl'] = 'failure url';
$hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";

    $hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);
    $hash_string = '';
    foreach ($hashVarsSeq as $hash_var)
    {
        $hash_string .= isset($posted[$hash_var]) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
        $hash_string .= '|';
    }
    $hash_string .= $SALT;
    $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));

Hope it helps you.
```

Comment: @Mohsin did you added all required parameters?

Comment: @Bhusan you can see all my parameters here https://github.com/mohsinbhaai/Payment_Gateway/blob/master/index.php

Comment: Please change your hash sequence to below:
        $hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";

Comment: What about another line?? for ex amount field... what name should I give there? I change hash sequence